# XML Elements with Components

Tags: xml

Can anyone explain the prime difference between doing something like:

`<car>
   <color>
       Blue
   </color>
</car>`

**VERSUS**

```
<car color="blue" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Difference is only in logical meaning. Usually inner elements are used to store data, and attributes - to express a property or behavior (that is not a part of the data).

Attributes can't contain multiple values, describe structures and they are not expandable (for future changes).